# How to configure Log4j2 properties file to allow write logs in console and file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

How to do a proper configuration for log4j2 properties file to make logger write information in console and file.

For now logger creates file, but it doesn't write info there.

Here is my property file:

```
name = LogConfig
property.filename = Logs
appenders = file, console

# File configuration
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName = ${filename}/Logs.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n

# Console configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n

# Configuration of the file logger
loggers = file
logger.file.name = infoFile
logger.file.level = DEBUG
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRefs.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = DEBUG
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
```

Here is file with test where I use logger:

```
package ru.atom.chat;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ChatClient.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ChatClientTest {
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ChatClientTest.class);

@Test
public void login() {
    log.debug("This is a debug message");
    log.info("This is an info message");
    log.warn("This is a warn message");
    log.error("This is an error message");
    log.fatal("This is a fatal message");
}
}
```

After running test I get in the console a proper logging:

> 2018-07-14 19:03:13.870  INFO 17106 --- [           main]
>   r.a.c.ChatClientTest                     : This is an info message
>   2018-07-14 19:03:13.870  WARN 17106 --- [           main]
>   r.a.c.ChatClientTest                     : This is a warn message
>   2018-07-14 19:03:13.870 ERROR 17106 --- [           main]
>   r.a.c.ChatClientTest                     : This is an error message
>   2018-07-14 19:03:13.871 FATAL 17106 --- [           main]
>   r.a.c.ChatClientTest                     : This is a fatal message

But the log file doesn't have this info. It only contains some Spring logs :-(

> 19:03:09.801 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner -
>   SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class
>   ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest] 19:03:09.815 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating
>   CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class
>   [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
>   19:03:09.912 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating
>   BootstrapContext using constructor [public
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
>   19:03:09.989 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating
>   TestContextBootstrapper for test class [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest]
>   from class
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
>   19:03:10.043 [main] INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper
>   - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
>   19:03:10.048 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did
>   not detect default resource location for test class
>   [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest]: class path resource
>   [ru/atom/chat/ChatClientTest-context.xml] does not exist 19:03:10.049
>   [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did
>   not detect default resource location for test class
>   [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest]: class path resource
>   [ru/atom/chat/ChatClientTestContext.groovy] does not exist
>   19:03:10.050 [main] INFO 
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could
>   not detect default resource locations for test class
>   [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest]: no resource found for suffixes
>   {-context.xml, Context.groovy}. 19:03:10.245 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could
>   not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type
>   [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class
>   [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest] 19:03:10.684 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper
>   - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [ru.atom.chat.ChatClientTest]: using defaults. 19:03:10.685 [main]
>   INFO 
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper
>   - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]:
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
>   19:03:10.751 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper
>   - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener]
>   ....

How to write logs from that JUnit test to file? Help me please, I'm a beginner.

Comment: you might need to exclude spring's default logging dependency from maven/gradle. Check out this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging) about logging.

Comment: I have already done it. Here is this line in my build.gradle

`configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}`